# Get a list of indices around a certain point - is there a more efficient way?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to work with a 2D grid of numbers, and I often need to gather a list of indices surrounding the point (x,y) in that grid. The grid is a np_array in itself, and I'm not as adept to numpy to use its advanced functions, so I go the more "Pascal" way like this:

```
neighbors=[[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1]]
result=[]
for i in neighbors:
    if (x+i[0]>=0) and (x+i[0]<dims[0]) and (y+i[1]>=0) and (y+i[1]<dims[1]):
        result.append([x+i[0],y+i[1]])
return result
```

`dims` here is a shape of that grid. I wonder if there is a more convenient and faster way already implemented in Numpy. Ultimately I'd like to create a "view" of original array that is a 8-neighborhood of a target not including the target, that would have changes in values reflected on the original array. I know it's possible because `a.T` is already a view of `a`, so the functionality exists. But how to make one? I don't even care if it'll be an 1-D.

Comment: If you want to do this in numpy, start by working with numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 3x3 (or smaller) box, you can figure out the limits and take a slice:

```
top = max(x - 1, 0)
left = max(y - 1, 0)
bottom = min(x + 1, arr.shape[0])
right = min(y +1, arr.shape[1])
result = arr[top:bottom, left:right]
```

If you just want the indices, you can create the `slice` objects that `top:bottom` and `left:right` get turned into:

```
result = (slice(top, bottom), slice(left, right))
```

You can use this tuple directly:

```
arr[result]
```

If you want a view into the original data rather than a copy, you must use a slice. For the data to have consistent strides (and therefore be representable as a slice), it must include the point of interest in addition to its neighbors.

Comment: Looks nice, but doesn't return the exact list of indices I was seeking. However, using slices looks promising, and I think I can cope with the center point being included in data. In fact I went with slicing `np.indices(dims)` and converting these into an 1D array like `[[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[6,5],[6,6],[6,7]]` for further use.

Comment: I made a typo (four actually) that I've fixed now. Should be better now